# Hi, is there any way to work on the same MySQL workbench database simultaneously from different devices at a time?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to share my MySQL workbench database with my project members so that we can maintain the same database instances, and data throughout the project. Is there any way to work on collaboration from different devices without importing and exporting processes in MySQL workbench?

I didn't find any solution rather than import-export

Answer (score 0):

Terminology is everything. MySQL Workbench is a tool for managing MySQL databases, and MySQL is a database server intended to work in a shared environment.

Assuming that MySQL is running on your machine then all you need do is

- make sure that the firewall allows traffic to port 3306 from your network,
- give your colleagues the IP address of your machine,
- create some users for them to use.

Then your colleagues can connect their own copies of MySQL Workbench to the MySQL server running on your machine.

This does require that your computer is on and connected to the network all the time your colleagues want to use MySQL, so you might find it convenient to build a small server to run it instead.